# AWS user pool vs facebook login backend authentication

Tags: aws-sdk, facebook-login, amazon-cognito

I am using facebook login and user pool login for application. After registering user in user pool I send .getAccessToken().getJwtToken() to backend and verify using  private $jku = 'https://cognito-idp.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/xxxxxxx/.well-known/jwks.json'

After facebook login which token I should use to authentication user? Is it possible to do without any changes to backend

Comment: Do you perform Facebook login by adding Federated Identity to AWS Cognito as shown here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/facebook.html ?

Comment: Yes, I am using Federated identify